South indian movie about 3 people who meet on a train and come to village
I am forgetting the name of the movie. The movie starts in a train, the protagonist or the hero of the movie is an IT person but he is pretty much introvert and he has to go to some place to show people about a project that he had worked on and only he knew about the project. He doesn't like travelling, he is weird in lot of ways. 
He meets the heroine in the train but doesn't dare to speak much. There is an elderly person who is going to some place to get medicines for his wife. Due to some reason, his mobile drops out of his pocket. The elderly gentleman had come to know that his wife had become serious and hence drops the idea to get medicine and starts returning home. The heroine, the hero and the elderly gentleman start for the village. They have many adventures due to which our hero also opens a bit. Once they reach the village, the elderly gentleman comes to know his wife is passed away. 
Actually what had happened was that the hero had picked the dropped phone and had heard that the elderly gentleman’s wife had passed away and either for compassion, or due to humanity or reasons unexplained he doesn't feel like leaving the old man and the girl and accompanies them. At the very end the hero and heroine meet. 
Does anybody know the name of the movie ? This was in 2012/2013 and a good movie. 
Language - Some south Indian language, either Tamil, Telugu or Malayalam. 
Year - 2012 or 2013. 

Sounds like the Malayalam movie North 24 Kaatham from 2013. 

Fahad Fazil is a geeky software professional who suffers from an
  Obsessive-compulsive disorder. On a trip to Trivandrum for a
  conference, he ends up at Paravur railway station with two strangers -
  Nedumudi Venu a veteran politician and Swathi Reddy a social worker.
  Fahad has to interrupt his journey and go to the other side of the
  state to help Nedumudi Venu, reach his home in Kozhikode, where his
  wife is critically ill. The journey becomes a learning experience for
  Fahad. The film is about the interplay between the above three main
  characters.

The movie won the National Film Award for Best Feature Film in Malayalam. It is written and directed by debutante director Anil Radhakrishnan Menon.
